# What is the implicit return type of NSLocale objectForKey method?

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol, nslocale

I have an iOS project with an `UIViewController` that contains an `UISegmentedControl` called `sizeSegmentedControl`. I want `sizeSegmentedControl` to display `cm` (for centimeter) in its left segmentIndex and `in` (for inch) in its right segmentIndex. When I build the project, I also want `sizeSegmentedControl` to select the segmentIndex corresponding to the device locale length unit. Therefore, I started with the following code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var sizeSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        sizeSegmentedControl.setTitle(NSLengthFormatter().unitStringFromValue(0, unit: .Centimeter), forSegmentAtIndex: 0)
        sizeSegmentedControl.setTitle(NSLengthFormatter().unitStringFromValue(0, unit: .Inch), forSegmentAtIndex: 1)

        sizeSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = NSLocale.currentLocale().objectForKey(NSLocaleUsesMetricSystem)!.boolValue == true ? 0 : 1            
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }    

}
```

Everything works fine with this code but I know that it is not safe to unwrap an optional without doing it inside an optional binding (`-objectForKey:` returns `AnyObject?`). So I changed my code inside `-viewDidLoad` to this:

```
sizeSegmentedControl.setTitle(NSLengthFormatter().unitStringFromValue(0, unit: .Centimeter), forSegmentAtIndex: 0)
sizeSegmentedControl.setTitle(NSLengthFormatter().unitStringFromValue(0, unit: .Inch), forSegmentAtIndex: 1)

if let localeSystem: AnyObject = NSLocale.currentLocale().objectForKey(NSLocaleUsesMetricSystem) {
    sizeSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = localeSystem.boolValue == true ? 0 : 1
}
```

This code works but the problem now is that I doubt `AnyObject` is the real type of `let localeSystem`. I had a look inside `NSLocale.h` and in the *NSLocale Class Reference* documentation but couldn't find more on its type. So my question is: how can I know the real type of `let localeSystem`?

Thanks.

Comment: Could it be a `NSNumber`? It seems to work with `NSNumber`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001224-47535) states

> `NSLocaleUsesMetricSystem`
>
> The key for the flag that indicates whether the locale uses the metric
>   system. The corresponding value is a **Boolean NSNumber object**. If the
>   value is NO, you can typically assume American measurement units (for
>   example, the statute mile).

and you can check that at runtime with an *optional cast*:

```
if let localeSystem = NSLocale.currentLocale().objectForKey(NSLocaleUsesMetricSystem) as? NSNumber {
   ...
}
```